How do I decode the image data in MS Word pasted content that contains images?
I'm trying to write a processor so that when a user pastes 'HTML' from MS Word, we can clean up the gobbledegook that MSWord creates, and convert it to clean HTML. I've got all of the bullet-point and other formatting working, but am now trying to extract the content from the images. Word seems to do this by including a comment section, which includes a 'tag' of the form:
  <o:gfxdata="blah"/>

where 'blah' appears to be the image data encoded as Base64.
I've got some C# code to process this, using the HTML Agility Pack, and I'm attempting to:

Convert the comment into an <img> tag
Set the img src to embedded base64 data

The code looks like this:
private void ExtractEmbeddedImages(HtmlDocument doc)
{
     const string startTag = "o:gfxdata=\"";

     // Find all the comments in the clipboard content
     var comments = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()");

     foreach ( var comment in comments )
     {
         var str = comment.InnerHtml;

         int pos = str.IndexOf( startTag );

         if(pos != -1)
         {
             int dataStart = pos + startTag.Length;
             int dataEnd = str.IndexOf( "\">", dataStart);

             if( dataEnd != -1 )
             {
                 int length = dataEnd - dataStart;
                 // Get the base64 data
                 string base64Data = str.Substring(dataStart, length).Trim();

                 // Create the src value for the img element
                 var src = $"data:image/png;base64,{base64Data}";
                 var imgNode = doc.CreateElement("img");
                 imgNode.Attributes.Add("src", src);

                 // Replace the entire comment with the img element
                 comment.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(imgNode, comment);
             }
         }
     }
}

It all seems to work great.... except that in the browser, the image renders as a placeholder.
It seems like the base64 data isn't a valid image stream.
Does anyone know what the actual process should be for decoding the images to extract them? It seems like there's very little information about the MSWord paste format out on the web.
